# How does Pip install libraries that include a command line tool?

Tags: python

Trying to troubleshoot something:

```
$ sudo -H python -m pip install -U wstool setuptools rosdep rosinstall rosinstall_generator rospkg catkin-pkg Distribute sphinx
```

And yet after doing that,

```
$ wstool init -j8 src kinetic-desktop-wet.rosinstall
bash: wstool: command not found
```

How do I make it so that wstool is available as a command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a module can install command prompt commands. Try to call them by first typing "python -m". This tells cmd that what you are referencing is a python module.

```
>>>python -m pyautogui
```

Install the pyautogui module, and type in this command if you want a basic example. I hope this helped

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Where is pip in your example? In my example I am doing `python -m pip install ...` and the installed pip module that is not showing up as a command line utility Is `wstool`. Can you explain further?

Comment: After python -m pip installing the module, type in python -m (module name), and any modifiers to run the cmd commands.

Comment: Didn't work...~ python -m wstool
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: No module named wstool.__main__; 'wstool' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: Sorry ): I don't know how to help.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: No problem. I hope you can find help.